# Need sidebars to display vertically on mobile with unusual ordering

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive, sidebar

This is the display that I need for desktop and mobile:

[image]

I have 3 columns. Column 1 (left sidebar), column 2 (main div) and column 3 (right sidebar.

Column 2 has content A, B, C and D.

On mobile devices I need the columns to be 100% width with the ordering of

Column 2, Column 1, Column 3.

But I need the order of the content on mobile devices to be:

Column 2 content A, Column 1, Column 3, Column 2 Content B, Column 2 Content C, Column 2 Content D.

This is what I'm using:

```
    @media screen (max-width: 1023px), (min-width: 799px) {

    }
    .column2 {
            position:absolute;top:300px;left:180px;width: calc(100% - 360px);
            left: 180px; text-align: center;
    }
    .column1 {
        position:absolute;top:50px;left:0px;width:180px;
    }

    .column3 {
        position:absolute;top:50px;right:0px;width:180px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {

    }
    .column2 {
            position:absolute;top:430px;left:180px;width: calc(100% - 360px);
            left: 180px;text-align: center;
    }
    .column1 {
        position:absolute;top:50px;right:0px;width:180px;

    }
    .
    .column3 {
        position:absolute;top:50px;right:0px;width:180px;height:50px;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {

    .column2 {

    }
    .column1 {

    }
    .column3 {

    }
}
```

The problem is that the above code causes mobile devices to display as Column 2 A,B,C,D - Column 2, Column 3. When I actually need Col 2A, Col 1, Col 3, Col 2B, Col 2C, Col 2D.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I found that I had to use margin-top instead of position:absolute for column2, and that I had to keep the div open for the Column2B,C,D,E content. Column 3 also had to go into column 2 which caused me to have to set the position to negative pixels to compensate for column 2s positioning.

If anyone has a better solution for this I'll accept your answer instead of my own.

Here is my solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/jc5Lsqcj/

```css
@media screen (max-width: 1023px), (min-width: 799px) {

    }
    .column2 {
            position:absolute;top:50px;left:180px;width: calc(100% - 360px);
            left: 180px; text-align: center;
    }
    .column1 {
        position:absolute;top:50px;left:0px;width:180px;
    }

    .column3 {
        position:absolute;top:0px;right:-180px;width:180px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {

    }
    .column2 {
            margin-top:5px;left:180px;width: calc(100% - 360px);
            left: 180px;text-align: center;
    }
    .column1 {
        position:absolute;top:50px;right:0px;width:180px;

    }
    .
    .column3 {
        position:absolute;top:-50px;right:-180px;width:180px;height:50px;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {

    .column2 {

    }
    .column1 {

    }
    .column3 {

    }
}
```

```html
<div class="column1">fds<hr /></div>

<div class="column2">fff

<div class="column3">qqq<hr /></div>

<br>ggg ppp<br><br>
  qqqq
</div>
```